Issue with external libraries in CMake
I am trying to build this test application, linking it to the Net-SNMP external library. This is a test project based on Makefiles, and I need to convert it to CMake.
This is what happens:

CMake runs with no issues.
Build gives this error:

Error 'netsnmp_REL-NOTFOUND', needed by 'SimpleApplication.exe', missing and no known rule to make it / ninja


Will the link be successful? (TODO, after the previous step is fixed)

This is the CMakeLists.txt file (to simplify I commented the debug part out):
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.26)

project(SimpleApplication VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

find_library(netsnmp_REL NAMES netsnmp)
#find_library(netsnmp_DBG NAMES netsnmpd)
add_library(netsnmp STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(netsnmp PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${netsnmp_REL}"
  IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "RELEASE"
 #IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${netsnmp_DBG}"
 #IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "RELEASE;DEBUG"
)

add_executable(SimpleApplication snmpdemoapp.c)

set_property(TARGET SimpleApplication PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(NET_SNMP_INCLUDE_PATH "E:/net-snmp-5.8/include/")
set(NET_SNMP_WIN_INCLUDE_PATH "E:/net-snmp-5.8/win32/")
set(NET_SNMP_LIB_PATH "E:/net-snmp-5.8/win32/lib/release/")

target_include_directories(SimpleApplication PRIVATE ${NET_SNMP_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_include_directories(SimpleApplication PRIVATE ${NET_SNMP_WIN_INCLUDE_PATH})

target_link_directories(SimpleApplication PRIVATE ${NET_SNMP_LIB_PATH})
find_library(SNMP_LIB netsnmp ${NET_SNMP_LIB_PATH})
target_link_libraries(SimpleApplication PRIVATE netsnmp)

#find_package(netsnmp REQUIRED)

This is the directory structure on disk:

E:\net-snmp-examples\SimpleApplication\CMakeLists.txt
E:\net-snmp-5.8\win32\lib\release

Another question: is this CMakeLists.txt file stylistically good, according to "Modern CMake"? Is there a way to skip the explicit library source and binary paths?
Platform:

Windows 11
Visual Studio 2022
CMake 3.3.2


find_library(netsnmp_REL NAMES netsnmp) -> find_library(netsnmp_REL NAMES netsnmp REQUIRED)

Adding REQUIRED I get: CMake Error CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_library): Could not find netsnmp_REL using the following names: netsnmp

So the line find_library(netsnmp_REL NAMES netsnmp) has failed to find the library. Note, that when executing this line, CMake has no hints about its location.

@Tsyvarev - I specify the location with this line: find_library(SNMP_LIB netsnmp ${NET_SNMP_LIB_PATH}). Maybe it is in the wrong place?

The error message you noted in the comments specifically about the 5th line. The line with find_library(SNMP_LIB ...)  comes later, so it is not executed.
